# magento 1.9 custom module fronted error 404

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, xml

I have problem to acces the custom module frontend controller.

I am following a basic tutorial to build a custom module.
These are the files I've edited:

> /var/www/html/magento/app/etc/modules/WaPoNe_Helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <WaPoNe_Helloworld>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
    </WaPoNe_Helloworld>
  </modules>
</config>
```

> /var/www/html/magento/app/code/WaPoNe/Helloworld/controllers/
>                IndexController.php

```
  class WaPoNe_Helloworld_IndexController extends 
                     Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

       public function indexAction() {
              echo 'Hello World!';
       }
    }
```

> /var/www/html/magento/app/code/WaPoNe/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <WaPoNe_Helloworld>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </WaPoNe_Helloworld>
      </modules>
    <frontend>
       <routers>
         <helloworld>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
              <module>WaPoNe_Helloworld</module>
              <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
            </args>
          </helloworld>
       </routers>
     </frontend>
  </config>
```

When I try to access the module frontend with this link:

```
http://localhost/magento/helloworld/index
http://localhost/magento/helloworld
http://localhost/magento/index.php/helloworld/index
```

I get error 404 not found.

Comment: Did you clear cache from admin?

Comment: cache is disabled.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your code into local or community folder :

Follow this below code and add in your file :

> /app/etc/modules/WaPoNe_Helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
       <modules>
          <WaPoNe_Helloworld>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
          </WaPoNe_Helloworld>
       </modules>
 </config>
```

> /app/code/local/WaPoNe/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <WaPoNe_Helloworld>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </WaPoNe_Helloworld>
      </modules>
    <frontend>
       <routers>
         <helloworld>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
              <module>WaPoNe_Helloworld</module>
              <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
            </args>
          </helloworld>
       </routers>
     </frontend>
  </config>
```

> /app/code/local/WaPoNe/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class WaPoNe_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
   public function indexAction() {
          echo 'Hello World!';
   }
}
```